# SAMBA4 as Active Directory DC: Linux computer and changing password

Tags: linux, active-directory, samba4

I have successfully joined computer to the SAMBA4 DC and successfully logging in!

Now the question is...how Linux users now can change their own passwords?

I guess it's to use "passwd" command. But it's not changing the password.

It's complaining that the password doesn't meet to requirements (trust me, I tried hard and very hard password as well as medium hard and simple, short, long...).

I think this must be done in some other way right?

This is really important...

I tried to force user to change his password on next login. The Linux (Ubuntu 11.04) is really asking for current password and asking for a new password twice. but the password, again, is not changing anyways.

Can you give me a hint?

Comment: There's a number of methods that can be used to authenticate a Linux system against Active Directory; which are you using?

Comment: I'm using through Likewise open, if I got the question right.

Comment: @Shane, sorry I should have noticed that it's actually a SAMBA4 and not Microsoft XXXX Server's AD, this is a major notice. But may be answering to the initial question about Active Directory would help in my case too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was due to password minimum age restriction.

You have to set this: **samba-tool pwsettings set --min-pwd-age=0**